# How to test iphone p2p aplications?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, bluetooth, ios-simulator, p2p

Is there a way to test iphone OS 3.0 p2p applications?
Can I run multiple iphone simulator instances? Aperantly no.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put up a detailed post on how to do this a couple weeks ago, so I'll just refer you to it: http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/06/18/debugging-peer-to-peer-and-wifi-apps-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Try to get permission from work or someplace with several computers on a LAN to run several instances. This will let you test network stuff, too.

Comment: ok, but that wouldn´t be the right scenario for testing the new 3.0 gamekit p2p apps. They work with bluetooth. am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must use 2 hardware devices for testing gamekit p2p connections.

Comment: No need for fancy markup, and please don't include comments in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=670173) you will need to test it on two real devices.

Comment: I got this link from dlamblin's answer

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should be able to run two instances of the iPhone Simulator by duplicating it..

Run the simulator as normal for phone 1.

For the second, go to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/` and copy (not move) the application somewhere (your Desktop?). When you run the copy, it will ask where the Developer Tools are installed and the application to run. Provide this and it *should* run a second copy.

Also, perhaps you could test it on both your real phone and the simulator?

Comment: doesn´t work, can´t run 2 instances of the sim at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

activate tethering on your iPhone
connect your mac with the simulator on it to the phone

Now you can test the gamekit on your sim and your iPhone

(I also have internet-sharing activated on my macbook - but I think the tethering-part is important... oh, this implies that bluetooth is running on the iPhone and the mac, of course)...

I'm pretty happy I found this solution - this was a major drawback...

Comment: Yes - I'm using it right now. Works like a charm...

Here's my setup:

MacBook (white) and iPhone 3GS
Don't really think this matters, though... :)

Lemme know if it works for you, too!

Answer (score -1):

I try to the same test on my macbook OS5.0 and iPhone 3gs , the iPhone simulator app can see the iPhone device via the app , but can not connected ... does this problem cause the bluetooth device is unauthorized ?

install VMware seem great but  too trouble...